# MongoWriteException: InsertOne has MongoDB.Driver.MongoBulkWriteException as inner exception

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Original exception:

> fail: MyMicroServiceMigrator.Services.MainBackgroundService[0] A write
> operation resulted in an error.  WriteError: { Category :
> "DuplicateKey", Code : 11000, Message : "E11000 duplicate key error
> collection: VrcProd.mycollection index: *id* dup key: { _id:
> ObjectId('62d70fb8e12940a8ab7527d6') }" }.

Inner Exception:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoBulkWriteException`1[Models.VRC.Collections.MyCollection]: A bulk write operation resulted in one or more errors. WriteErrors: [ { Category : "DuplicateKey", Code : 11000, Message : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: VrcProd.mycollection index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('62d70fb8e12940a8ab7527d6') }" } ].    at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWrite(IClientSessionHandle
> session, IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<>c__DisplayClass28_0.b__0(IClientSessionHandle
> session)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSession[TResult](Func`2
> func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWrite(IEnumerable`1 requests,
> BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.<>c__DisplayClass68_0.<InsertOne>b__0(IEnumerable`1
> requests, BulkWriteOptions bulkWriteOptions)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.InsertOne(TDocument document, InsertOneOptions options, Action`2 bulkWrite)

So the problem is why is there MongoBulkWriteException as inner exception when calling InsertOne?

Upsert method:

```
    public void Upsert<T>(T entity, bool newEntity = false) where T : IMongoEntityVRC
    {
        try
        {
            if (newEntity)
            {
                this.Insert(entity);
            }
            else
            {
                this.FindAndUpdate(entity);
            }
        } catch (MongoWriteException e) when (ExceptionUtils.GetErrorCode(e) == DuplicateKeyCode)
        {
            throw new EntityUniqueConstraintViolationException(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

I wont post whole code of the caller method because its irrelevant.
But the logic is pretty simple to map from one type (type A) to the new type (type B).

```
   // pseudo code of the caller method:
   foreach (var item in items)
   {
      // find existing
      var myEntity = FindmyEntity(item.id);
      // map the object of the new type from this entity
      var mappedEntity = CreateEntity(myEntity ?? new MappedEntity(), myEntity);
      // upsert or insert depending if existing entity was found
      Upsert(entity, myEntity is null);
   }
```

Now my question is why do I get the MongoBulkWriteException when I'm calling InsertOne, it doesn't make any sense...

Comment: The database has a primary key and your input has a duplicate key.  Either the database already has the value or the input data has the value twice.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question...

Comment: Yes it does.  It is what caused the exception.

Comment: The question is: "So the problem is why is there MongoBulkWriteException as inner exception when calling InsertOne?"

Comment: Because key is already in the database.

Answer (score 1):

All CRD (in `CRUD`) operations are done via `Bulk` internally. So when you call Insert, effectively you call a `Bulk` operation. This is why you see `MongoBulkWriteException`